# P-value between expectation and observation of a Poisson process

Tags: normal-distribution, p-value, poisson-distribution

Probably this is a question with a simple answer, but I was not able to wrap my head around it. I want to determine the compatibility of observing a number of events $N_{obs}$, under the hypothesis that the underlying distribution is a Poisson for which I know that the distribution of the mean $\mu$ is a Gaussian with mean $\bar\mu$ and std. dev $\sigma$.

I tried the naive approach, setting $\sigma_{obs} = \sqrt{N_{obs}}$ and computing the $\chi^2$ of the two as: $\chi^2 = \frac{(N_{obs}-\mu)^2}{\sigma_{obs}^2 + \sigma^2}$. And then I tried computing the the $p$-value using this $\chi^2$ assuming the number of degrees of freedom is 1. The results seem somewhat OK, but I'm not sure this approach is valid since the errors on the observation are not Gaussian.

Any help on this will be appreciated!

I apologize in advance if a similar question was already asked and answered. I could not find it in the forum.

**EDIT 1**

To be more specific, I have 2 cases I want to deal with:

1. $\bar{\mu}=30; \sigma=5.0$ and $N_{obs}=33$.
2. $\bar{\mu}=0.5; \sigma=0.05$  and $N_{obs}=0$.

As suggested in the comments, I simulated for each case 100 times the mean of the Poisson for the null hypothesis and for each mean I sampled randomly the resulting Poisson. The plots are shown below.
[image: Case 1]

[image: Case 2]

Comment: You seem to have a completely specified null hypothesis, simulate, say 100 observations from that null distribution, and plot (maybe a dotplot ) those together with your observation!

Comment: I updated the post to include the plot(s).